# Shutdown command from UI restarts system in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: shutdown, restart

I have Ubuntu 14.04.2 installed on Lenovo Flex 2 laptop. My problem is that whenever I select shutdown from the menu, the laptop restarts instead of completely shutting down. 
Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Check your bios setting - After Power Off Wake=On or Off

Comment: @ubuntu99: this does not happen with my Windows 8.1 which is in the other partition

Comment: Did you try the answer i posted editing grub file?
and what is effect of sudo halt ? (Shutdown or Restart)

Answer (score 1):

The shutdown from the UI rarely works for me.  It has been very iffy in versions for the last 4 years.

Someone might be able to place insight on directly why.  But for a resolution you can install cairo-dock and use that UI shutdown problem free.

You can install it with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
```

Now run it from the Launch button.  Use this alternate shutdown option.  It'll work every time.

I didn't include this in my original answer because it appeared that you were trying to use the GUI.

This will also work every time:

```
$ sudo shutdown -h now
```

You can also reboot the computer by issuing:

```
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

Check other cli shutdown options with:

```
$ man shutdown
```

Of course you can put this in a script and create a [myshutdown.desktop](https://askubuntu.com/a/144210/29012) icon to execute the shutdown script with a click.

Comment: This would not worry me too much currently I guess ;) If shutdown did not work, I would use __hibernate__ instead. Because, unlike in previous 'Buntus, hibernate will always work as a true shutdown (at least here on my box) instead of a quick shutdown-and-restore as it is designed. IOW, I am always required to relogin, whilst with a *working* hibernate, I would *not* be required to do that. Worked great in Lubuntu Trusty.

Comment: @syntaxerror: actully, hibernate does not wake up my wifi . i have to restart my system everytime i put my laptop to hibernate.

Comment: Yes, I can believe, read what I wrote. Most of it is __totally broken__ at the moment. However, as I don't have wifi on the machine I was just speaking of, I can't make much judgment about this side of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may create script for shutdown by executing following commands :

```
sudo gedit shutdown_system
```

and write `sudo poweroff` in the file and save it.

then change permission by `chmod +x shutdown_system`

Execute the file for shutting down the system.

```
./shutdown_system
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: acpi tricks doesnt work

Comment: What about sudo halt ? Does it shutdown or restart the system.

Comment: it gets stuck. doesnt shutdown cleanly

Comment: Try this sudo init 0. Also sudo shutdown -h now and also try sudo poweroff -f. Tell me what happens on each of these commands.

Comment: init 0 - restarts, shutdown -f : drops to single user mode, poweroff - shuts down the laptop

Comment: Answer updated...